# JSON parse and encoding with generic types

Tags: arrays, json, generics, libgdx

I have an generic array of objects:

```
    static Array<Level> allLevels = new Array<Level>();
```

Now I want to encode it to json like this:

```
    Json json = new Json();
    String levelsJsonString = json.prettyPrint(allLevels);
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to reverse this process:

```
allLevels = json.fromJson(Level.class, levelsJsonString);
```

It is raising that Array and Level are incompatible types. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's always problem with passing **generic type class** to a json **fromJson()** method.

The simpliest workarround is just to wrap Array type like:

```
    public class Levels
    {
        public static Array<Level> allLevels = new Array<Level>();
    }
```

Then you can use it just like

```
    Levels.allLevels.add( new Level() ); //etc...
```

and retrieve it from JSON like

```
    ... = json.fromJson(Levels.class, jsonLevels);
```

passing the wrapping class **class object** to fromJson method. The same you are doing hen converting to JSON - pass wrapping class not just Array object

```
    String levelsJsonString = json.prettyPrint(Levels.allLevels);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks.