# Serialization of my GameState to JSON in libGdx is not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, json, serialization, libgdx

I am having trouble saving my GameState to JSON.

Originally I was saving the GameState to JSON like this:

```
Json json = new JSON();
String save = json.prettyPrint(state);
```

And I was loading it as follows:

```
json.fromJson(GameState.class, save);
```

The State was not loading correctly, however, so I ran a little test. I did the following:

```
class Car
{
    public int id;
    public Color color;
    public Speed speed;

    public Car(int id, Color color, Speed speed)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.id = id;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

class Speed
{
    enum ASpeed
    {
        FAST, MEDIUM, SLOW;
    }

    ASpeed speed;

    public Speed()
    {
        speed = ASpeed.FAST;
    }
}
```

And in `create`

```
@Override
public void create()
{
    Json json = new Json();
    Car car = new Car(1, Color.RED, new Speed());
    String carSave = json.prettyPrint(car);

    System.out.println(carSave);
}
```

The result I get is this:

```
{
    id:1
    color:{
        r:1
        a:1
    }
    speed:{}
}
```

I see why my game was not properly loading; it was not properly serializing. My `GameState` is pretty much a class containing 3 `Array`s of data that needs to progress from game to game. I have the regular getter and setter methods as well as a couple dozen utility methods to access relevant data as follows:

```
//TODO: Possibly add an Array of Event instances to fire for each player when certain circumstances are met as well as a string-based flagging system that can be used in the events.
//TODO: Research threading API in libGdx and see about moving the game logic over to a seperate thread - since this class is used for game logic, consider moving this with it.
public class GameState
{
    private Array<Player> players;
    private Array<Planet> planets;
    private Array<Fleet> fleets;

    public GameState(Array<Player> players, Array<Planet> planets, Array<Fleet> fleets)
    {
        this.players = players;
        this.planets = planets;
        this.fleets = fleets;
    }

    public Fleet getFleet(int id)
    {
        if(id <= fleets.size)
        {
             return fleets.get(id);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Planet getPlanet(int id)
    {
        if(id <= planets.size)
        {
            return planets.get(id);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Player getPlayer(int id)
    {
        if(id <= players.size)
        {
            return players.get(id);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Of course, this isn't the best approach, but I only have about 100 of each field and do not plan to add much more, so this method serves my purpose fine. Each player contains an Array of `Integer` values used to fetch the relevant data. An example;

```
public class Player
{
    private final int id;

    //libGdx Color used by ShapeRenderer to display planets in the right political color
    private Color color;

    //Things that the game logic demands be accessible from each Player instance
    //TODO: Move these over to the libGdx IntegerArray when you have the time - this will avoid the boxing/unboxing penalty when accessing members.
    Array<Integer> allies;
    Array<Integer>desiredAllies;
    Array<Integer> enemies:
    Array<Integer> neutrals;
    Array<Integer> planets;
    Array<Integer> fleets;

    public Player(int id, Color color)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.color = color;
        allies = new Array<Integer>();
        planets = new Array<Integer>();
        fleets = new Array<Integer>();
        neutrals = new Array<Integer>();
        enemies = new Array<Integer>();
    }

    //Getters, Setters, and many, many utility methods.
}
```

The Planet, Player, and Fleet classes all have similar structure, even going so far as to implement the same Interface:

```
public interface IndexedGameObject extends GameObject
{
    int getID();
}
```

My game design and structure works well until it comes to serialization. I learned Json specifically to save my game, and I might have missed something. **Why does this design not work when serializing? Is there a way I can make it to work? If not, what possible solutions might work aside from writing my own save format? I have little experienceing in XML, would that work?**

Notes:

I am willing and able to write my own save format, but doing so in a consistent, readable-to-the-human-eye way will add a lot of overhead and maintenance and would waste time (as it is akin to writing a very small, not completely functional language and I would need to do a lot of general testing to ensure it is working properly) and energy that would be better spent developing and maintaining a more intuitive user interface. If there is no way JSON can serve my purposes, is there anything that can?

I would essentially have to rework my entire schedule (and yes, I keep a list of things I need do and when I should do them such as; Tuesday - Fix that annoying, nigh impossible to recreate button disappearing bug after school and homework).

My JSON should, in theory have a structure like this;

```
GameState ->
    fleets ->
        fleet ->
            owner: integer id of the player that owns this fleet.
            id: the index of this fleet in the Array
            locationID: integer id of the province this fleet is located in.
            originalTransports: final integer used for reinforcing.
            originalFighters: final integer used for reinforcing.
            originalFrigates: final integer used for reinforcing.
            originalDreadnaughts: final integer used for reinforcing.
            transports: number of troop transports currently in the fleet.
            fighters: the number of fighters currently in fleet.
            frigates: the number of frigates in this fleet.
            dreadnaughts: number of dreadnaughts in the fleet.
    players ->
        player ->
            id: int representing the index of this player in the GameState
            provinces: Integer Array representing the provinces owned by this player.
            allies: Integer Array representing the index of the other Players allied to this one.
            enemies: Integer Array representing the indices of the other players at war with this one.
            neutrals: Integer Array representing the players whom this player is neutral to
            desiredAllies: Integer Array representing the players who this player desires for allies - used mainly by the ai to determine who to send alliance offers to and who to accept them from.
            fleets: Integer Array representing the indices of the fleets of this player
    provinces ->
        province ->
            id: int representing the index of this province
            owner: int id of the owning player in the GameState
            name: String value. Text displayed on the screen when province selected.
            isUnderSiege: boolean. Read the variable name.
            colonies ->
                colony ->
                     name: String value. Displayed in the menu when the city is selected from the province info screen that pops up when the province is selected.
                     controller: The index of the controlling Player in the GameState.
                     population: int number of people who reside here. Used to calculate things such as how many ships this planet provides, or how much tax it gives to the player.
                     fortLevel: double representing the amount of organized military resistance this colony will give an attacker before surrendering.
                     growthRate: the number of births occurring in this colony every 60 ticks.
```

### EDIT:

The players Array and the fleets work properly. When I reach the provinces Array, things just get weird;

```
{
    planets:[
        //There should be 300 provinces. Instead 300 of these
        colonies: [ {},{},{},{},{},{},{} ]
    ]
}
```

And my class with relevant fields looks something like this;

```
public class Planet implements IndexedGameObject, Modifier
{
    private int id;

    private Array<Colony> colonies;

    public Planet(int id, Array<Colony> colonies)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.colonies = colonies;
    }

    //Utility methods + Getters/Setters
}

class Colony
{
    private int parentProvinceID;
    private ColonyType type;

    public Colony(int parentProvinceID, ColonyType type)
    {
        this.parentProvinceID = parentProvinceID;
        this.type = type;
    }

    //Some more irrelevant methods
}

enum ColonyType
{
    ADMINISTRATIVE, MILITARY, POPULATION;
}
```

Comment: Why is your enum wrapped in another class? What happens if you make the enum definition public, or move it out into its own file so it's not an inner class?

Comment: @Tenfour04 When I make it public nothing happens. I have not tried moving it into a separate file, but I will try.

Comment: Yea I think Tenfour04 is right about the enum definition being public. As far as arrays they should serialize just fine automatically. I don't see where you proved that not working above.

Comment: Does it actually have to be wrapped in another class? I haven't had trouble with enums and LibGDX's Json, but I've only used them in their own files. And I do use "complicated" enums that have methods and defined constructors, etc.

Comment: @Barodapride My laptop just ran out of power (on school bus on phone) but I will try it when I get home (in ~8 hours) and get back to you and Tenfour04 as soon as I can.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It just makes more sense in my mind to have things like `ColonyType` in the same file or nested in the class `Colony` and things like that. As for adding the `public` modifier to the enum, that makes sense since `Json.toJson()` needs to access the enum/subclass. Write the answer and I will probably accept it after confirming that it works.

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what's wrong with your object serialization. What does the json of your GameState look like? Is it working except for some enums? And I agree, you should define enums specific to a class within that class.

Comment: @Barodapride I will update the answer to include a small piece of the Json

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'd start by commenting your Colony class members and just leaving some simple field. See if that makes it into the json. Then start uncommenting fields until this happens again. If you can't get anything to show up maybe you're referencing the wrong Colony class (maybe you left another blank Colony class in another package).

Comment: Is your Speed class (or Colony class) an inner class? IIRC, Json chokes on non-static inner classes because of limitations to reflection.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, that was it. The Colony class was not an inner class but was defined in the same file as Planet (therefore was not public). My mistake, I probably should not have been working on a game when I had 3 hours of sleep because I actually intended for it to be an inner class. Both moving the faulty classes to where they belonged and putting them in their own file and making them public worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is being caused by **generic Arrays**. I suppose that it is not possible to JSON to serialize for example `Array<Player>`.

The solution is to wrap generic arrays - [take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813458/json-parse-and-encoding-with-generic-types) or to use not generic Array where it is possible (for exmaple **FloatArray** instead of **Array**).

---

On the other hand the structure of your logic seems to be like relational - meybe it would be more convenient to use some SQL techniques instead of keeping this in objects and serialize/deserialize? [Here you have some nutshell info](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx-users/wikis/SQLite.wiki)

Comment: What about the example I posted - the `Car` class serialized, but the result produced by the `Speed` instance member of `Car` was `speed:{}`? No `Array` was in use there.

Comment: To be honest I do not have experience with serializing *enums* but it seems that it is also impossible - [take a look at this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3143). You can make a little test with changing enum to String instance

Comment: Try changing your enum field to public and seeing if it shows up then.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making the enum fields `public static` and moving them into their parent classes - I had overlooked this, as pointed out by @Barodapride and @TenFour04.

```
public class Planet
{
    private Array<Colony> colonies;

    public static class Colony
    {
        private ColonyType type;
        private int parentProvinceID;

        public static enum ColonyType
        {
            ADMINISTRATIVE, MILITARY, POPULATION;
        }
    }
}
```

Serializes correctly.